# Filling area between 2 Plots made by coordinates with transparent

Tags: pgfplots, intersections

I am trying to fill the area between 2 plots with lil bit transparency. Actually i got with `fill between` this figure:

[image]

How can I only fill the difference between the two plots. Make the actual orange part white and the actual white part orange?

I tried it with the `split,every odd segment/.style={yellow}` but this only change the second orange part to yellow. Also with research in the pgfplot manual I wasnt able to handle it.

Here is my code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=X,
    ylabel=Y,
    %grid=major,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=8,
    smooth
    ]
    \addplot[name path=A,domain=0:5,color=red] {-(x-2.5)^(2)+6};
    \addplot[name path=B,domain=0:6,color=blue] {-(x-3.5)^(2)+6};
    \addplot [orange] fill between[
    of=A and B
    ];
    
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `intersection segments` as explained in the `pgfplots` manual, *Intersection Segment Recombination* (section 5.7.6 for manual revision 1.17, 2020/02/29).

In the code below, `sequence=R1 -- L2` means we connect the first intersection segment of the second input path (path denoted by `R` in this context) to the second intersection segment of the first input path (path denoted by `L` in this context). Then, the last point of the path we thus described is apparently automatically connected to its first point to form a closed path that can be filled, as shown in the example given p. 448 of the manual. It is also possible to explicitly close the path using `-- cycle` (cf. example p. 449):

```latex
\fill [orange,
       intersection segments={of=A and B, sequence=R1 -- L2}]
      -- cycle;
```

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=X,
    ylabel=Y,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=8,
    smooth
    ]
    \addplot[name path=A,domain=0:5,color=red] {-(x-2.5)^(2)+6};
    \addplot[name path=B,domain=0:6,color=blue] {-(x-3.5)^(2)+6};
    \fill [orange, intersection segments={of=A and B, sequence=R1 -- L2}];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the filling to be partly transparent, you can use for instance:

```latex
\fill [orange, fill opacity=0.2,
       intersection segments={of=A and B, sequence=R1 -- L2}];
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great thank you. But how is it possible to make the filling more transperent. Becuse a part of the x-axe is now missing.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please see the latest edit for an example with a partly transparent filling.